# Why can I not use KVC from an Objective-C object to a Swift Property?

Tags: objective-c, swift, key-value-coding, kvc

My team has decided that new files should be written in swift, and I am seeing an odd problem with using KVC in an Objective-C object to set a property on a Swift object.

My Objective-C sets a property like so: `[textObject setValue:0.0 forKey:@"fontSize"]`

My Swift object (`textObject`) has a custom setter/getter for this property.

```
   var fontSize: CGFloat? {
      get {
         return internalTextGraphic?.fontSize 
      }
      set {
            internalTextGraphic?.fontSize = newValue
      }
   }
```

However, if I set a breakpoint in the `set`, it never gets hit.

I have Objective-C objects that also get this same call, and I just implement
`-setFontSize`, and the execution enters properly.

Why can't I seem to get into my `set` method through `-setValueForKey`?
I have 100% confirmed the `textObject` is exists and is the correct type.

**EDIT**:
Martin R is correct, I had to make the type a non-optional.  This is my working code:

```
   var fontSize: CGFloat {
      get {
         var retFontSize: CGFloat = 0.0
         if let fontSize = internalTextGraphic?.fontSize {
            retFontSize = fontSize
         }
         return retFontSize
      }
      set {
         if let textGraphic = internalTextGraphic {
            textGraphic.fontSize = newValue
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is that a Swift optional struct or enum (in your case `CGFloat?`)
is not representable in Objective-C (and you won't see that property
in the generated `"Project-Swift.h"` header file). That becomes more obvious
if you mark the property 
explicitly with `@objc`, then you'll get the error message

```
error: property cannot be marked @objc because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

If you change the property type to the non-optional `CGFloat`
then KVC works as expected. It would also work with an optional
class type, such as `NSNumber?`.

Comment: *"a Swift optional is not representable in Objective-C"* — well, this is not true for optional classes / protocol types, but it is true for structs/enums, of which CGFloat is one.